# Revit: C# Addin to create studs at the corners

Tags: autodesk-forge, revit-api

We are using revit 2020 C# apis in our addin project.

We need to create studs in the external corners of model. Currently we are using dynamo script for this purpose. In dynamo player we need to select level and then we clicks on play button.

After completion dynamo script create studs in the every external corner at given level.

[output create studs using dynamo script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8IOOW.png)

[output create studs using dynamo script zoom view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJSMa.png)

Now we are planning to eliminate dynamo script and want to achieve this using c# revit api.

Can any please help me that how can we achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Edit your Dynamo script, analyse the source code, and recreate that in C#.

The images you attached help understand your requirement.

However, they do not explain how the current Dynamo script achieves what you need. For that, you can take a look at the Python source code executed by the Dynamo script. It uses the exact same .NET based Revit API as your C# add-in.

Comment: I am new to dynamo script, so I don't have any idea that how to get python source code from dynamo script. Could you please help me to get this python source code?